# How do I map a single Id in my domain model to multiple Ids in my data model using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi

I am attempting to create a new Web API using ASP.Net Core 3, Entity Framework Core, and AutoMapper against a previously existing database.  I will try to explain my problem briefly.

For the sake of example, assume the database has the following tables:

```
Person
--------------------
person_id    int PK
first_name   varchar
last_name    varchar
...other fields common to all Persons...

Owner
--------------------
owner_id     int PK, FK Person.person_id
...fields specific to Owners...

Renter
--------------------
renter_id   int PK, FK Person.person_id
...fields specific to Renters...
```

Note: The original developers of the database did not make the person_id an identity column.  They use a [UniqueIds] table and a stored procedure to fetch and increment Ids for tables in the database.

In the context of the data model objects, Person, Owner, and Renter are all distinct classes with their on DbSet<> properties in the DbContext.  The owner_id or renter_id is a person_id, and ties the tables together through a foreign key constraint.

From a Domain object perspective, I've designed the Owner and Renter domain classes as sub-classes of a Person class.

```
class Person { ... }
class Owner : Person { ... }
class Renter : Person { ... }
```

I'm still learning the plumbing of how to put all this together, which is proving to be difficult given the plethora of information available, which is sometimes incomplete, lacking context, or outdated.  So I really could use some up-to-date guidance.  What isn't clear to me:

- If I were using the data model directly, my application would be responsible for knowing that in order to create a new Owner record (i.e., add a new class instance to DbSet<Owner>), a new Person record with the same ID must be added to DbSet<Person>. So, I am assuming that a domain model in the layer that sits atop the data/persistence layer has to do something similar, and that AutoMapper will take care of ensuring the domain object's properties are properly mapped to the data objects if properly configured.
- With that in mind, when defining the domain model, should I define a separate OwnerId field in the Owner class and somehow map it in AutoMapper?  This seems rather sloppy to me, and relies on the consumer of my domain to ensure that OwnerId and PersonId from the base class hold the same value when creating a new Owner.

It would seem to me that AutoMapper should support the ability to represent the inheritance (which it does with `IMappingExression.Include` or `IMappingExression.IncludeBase`) and map Owner.PersonId (Domain) to both Owner.OwnerId and Person.PersonId in the data objects.  But I cannot find any practical examples of this.  Perhaps my Google Fu is failing me and similar question has been asked, but I could not find one.  Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you use inheritance in your entity framework model that the DB entity `Owner` extends from the DB entity `Person` just like your domain model? Then the entity framework knows that it has to create a row in the `dbo.Person` table first and use it's id to create a row in the `dbo.Owner` table as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have of your entity framework model. Also include your attempts on how to setup your automapper for your entity framework model.

Comment: Because of IP constraints, I cannot share any of my real source - which is why I posted a generic example of the setup for the problem.  In any case, I feel as though I am stumbling through unfamiliar territory with AutoMapper specifically.  Perhaps it simply isn't the right tool for the job.  But I suspect more is the case that I am simply missing some simple, elegant part of it all.  With respect to inheritance in EF Core, according to this web page, the type of inheritance you are talking about isn't supported yet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance